# Ubuntu update on Dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, nvidia

I have a dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop which has an NVidia graphics card and is HP inspiron 15700. The Ubuntu partition was in my D drive which was empty prior to the dual boot and the Windows was in my C drive. It was all working fine until I tried to update Ubuntu.

I tried to update my Ubuntu to 18.04 but my computer has crashed and now when I boot I see [image: these errors] (PKSC#7 signature not signed with a trusted key, couldn't get size etc).

I am a bit of a Ubuntu newbie and am unsure how to use initramfs or how to fix this. I have access to grub but am unsure what exactly to do with grub either. Please help. Any ideas would be enormously appreciated.

UPDATE:

I have now tried restoring to a previous kernel and get the login page for Ubuntu 18.04. However, when I try to login the screen goes back for a second and then returns to login. I cannot seem to log in.

Comment: It looks like your root-disk doesn't work. Try to boot on Live media (USB or DVD you installed from), and see if you can access the harddisk from there.

Comment: Disable secure boot

Comment: How would I disable secure boot @KristopherIves

Comment: It's a BIOS setting

Comment: Ah okay... What should I do to check that @SorenA? What is the aim of this?

Comment: There are hundreds of different BIOS menus so it's impossible to give you instructions for that. See your PC manufacturer information and look at the BIOS options.